# How to restore horizontal application menu in KDE Plasma 5?

Tags: kde, plasma5

I would like to restore the horizontal style in-application menu bar in KDE Plasma 5. Somehow I ended up with a single "control" menu item like this:

[image]

Using that requires two mouse clicks instead of one.

What I would like is the horizontal style in-application menu (just below the title bar) like this:

[image]

What are the steps for switching back?

The other questions on this topic discuss Global Menus, which I do not believe is related to my question about in-application menus. I am not using global (Unity or Mac style) menus.

Other questions / answers I looked at include:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/426002
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/489727
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/30180/menubar-hidden-in-all-kde-apps

Pressing CTRL-M does not resolve it. That appears to be a different issue. I have a menu, it's just not the one I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 19.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.15.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.57.0
Qt Version: 5.12.2
Kernel Version: 5.0.0-15-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
```

I've checked with Dolphin, Kate and Gwenview.

I think the problem is with the ☰ button in your title bar. Its presence suppresses the appearance of the horizontal menu.

Remove it by opening *System Settings > Application Style > Window Decorations > Buttons tab* and dragging the ☰ button off your title bar into the space below.

In Kate and Gwenview, the horizontal menu now can be toggled on/off with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

In Dolphin, now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> toggles between the horizontal menu and the Control (☰) button.

---

**Edit**

And it's the same with the Fedora 30 KDE Spin:

```
Operating System: Fedora 30
KDE Plasma Version: 5.15.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.58.0
Qt Version: 5.12.1
Kernel Version: 5.0.17-300.fc30.x86_64
OS Type: 64-bit
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me :-(.  KDE Neon, Plasma 5.18.2

Comment: @david.perez maybe post a separate question explaining what you have done and what doesn't work (with a couple of images)?

Comment: Solved, after removing a 2nd taskbar panel in my secondary monitor

Comment: I wanted to add that I was having this problem and it worked, but I had to completely close and re-open the affected programs.

Comment: Thank you! Yout Ctrl+M shortcut saved me lot of frustration.

Answer (score 1):

In System Settings -> Workspace -> Startup and Shutdown -> Background Services, uncheck the "Application menus daemon" then log out and back into Plasma again

From: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=167547&p=436510&hilit=horizontal+menu#p436510